# couchbase downloadAttachment progress returns -1 of -1

Tags: ios, couchbase, couchbase-lite

when i tried to download attachments 1 by 1 using downloadAttachment:(CBLAttachment*)attachement i get at progress of -1 of -1

heres my CBLReplicator

```
-(id)init{

self = [super init];

if (self) {
    self.database = [[CouchDBManagerOC sharedInstance]database];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:SYNC_RESOURCE];
    self.pullData = [self.database createPullReplication:url];
    [self.pullData setChannels:@[@"USERsuitesNewUserThisShouldBeUUID"]];
    [self.pullData setAuthenticator:[self authenticator]];
}

return self;}
```

---

here my downloading of image for couchbase remote

```
- (void)downloadImageAttachment:(CBLDocument *)doc 
  attachmentName:(NSString *)attachmentName 
  completionBlock:(downloadCompletionBlock) block
{
self.attachmentDocumentID = doc.documentID;
CBLAttachment *attachment = [doc.currentRevision attachmentNamed:attachmentName];
self.attachmentName = attachmentName;
self.completionBlock = block;

self.progress = [self.pullData downloadAttachment: attachment];
[self.pullData start];
[self.progress addObserver:self forKeyPath: @"fractionCompleted" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context: NULL];
[self.progress.userInfo addObserver: self forKeyPath: kCBLProgressErrorKey options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context: NULL];
}
```

since i my progress is not changing my KVO is not working too

Comment: Do you get the data anyway, even the progress value is wrong?

Comment: no sir. I didn't get the data.

Comment: I don't think downloading an attachment this way is valid since you never enabled [deferred attachment downloading](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/blob/66133e2ec76851ed16828f3b05476de0671ced3e/Source/API/CBLReplication.h#L80)

Comment: @borrrden sorry for the late reply sir . acutally I set the downloadAttachments = NO.. As the guide suggest but still it's not working